# Replace UIWindow

Tags: ios, cordova, touch, uiwindow

I'm using phonegap to develop web apps via js, but I would need certain functionality that can only be done in objective c. In detail I want to register touches on the webview, to trigger the automatic closure of overlayed views. Googling for "detect touches" brings up the solution that one should subclass `UIWindow` and overwrite `sendEvent` in order to detect if a desired view was touched.

This actually works quite well, but I noticed phonegap will already allocate and set an instance of `UIWindow`in their code, so I am unable to use the subclassed `UIWindow`. I thus found this solution to be working:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   bool res= [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

   // ok, now this part is kind of ugly
   // replace normal UIWindow with tap-detection enabled version

   [self.viewController.view removeFromSuperview];

   CGRect screenBounds = [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ];

   TapDetectWindow* tapWindow= [[[TapDetectWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];

   tapWindow.tapDelegate= self.logic;
   tapWindow.targetView= self.webView;

   self.window = tapWindow;
   self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

   [self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

   return res;
}
```

While this works like a charm (without any side effects yet), I was wondering if this would be a good approach, or if I'm going to break anything by replacing the `UIWindow` after it was already set up and made visible ... ?